# no se gurda correctamente el archivo .txt

Tags: c, archivo

Estoy haciendo un proyecto para la universidad sobre manejo de archivos en el manejo de una tienda, lo que se vende y compra (`modificaciones.txt`) y los productos que existen (`inventario.txt`),
lo cual no logré a comprender bien el tema y por más que intento estudiarlo sigo con las mismas trabas.

Mi problema es que al momento de ejecutar el código e ingresar un nuevo producto, este no se guarda y después de eso, ya no hace ninguna acción de manera correcta, un ejemplo es que me deja en blanco el archivo de texto o hace que este tenga inventario negativo, intenté usar `rewind()` para que se moviera el puntero y pudiera leer correctamente, pero al parecer ese no es el problema (o lo estoy poniendo de manera equivoca). Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void agregarProducto(FILE* archivoInventario) {
    int codigo;
    char nombre[100];
    int unidades;
    float precio;
    
    rewind(archivoInventario); // Restablecer el puntero del archivo al inicio

    printf("Ingrese el codigo del producto: ");
    scanf("%d", &codigo);

    // Verificación de código positivo
    if (codigo < 0) {
        printf("Solo se admiten numeros positivos. Vuelva a intentar.\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Ingrese el nombre del producto: ");
    getchar(); // Consumir el carácter de nueva línea anterior
    fgets(nombre, sizeof(nombre), stdin);
    nombre[strcspn(nombre, "\n")] = '\0'; // Eliminar el carácter de nueva línea al final

    printf("Ingrese el numero de unidades: ");
    scanf("%d", &unidades);

    printf("Ingrese el precio por unidad: ");
    scanf("%f", &precio);

    fprintf(archivoInventario, "%d %s %d %.2f\n", codigo, nombre, unidades, precio);
    printf("Producto agregado correctamente.\n");
    rewind(archivoInventario); // Restablecer el puntero del archivo al inicio
}

void venderProducto(FILE* archivoInventario, FILE* archivoModificaciones) {
    int codigo;
    int cantidad;

    printf("Ingrese el codigo del producto a vender: ");
    scanf("%d", &codigo);

    printf("Ingrese la cantidad a vender: ");
    scanf("%d", &cantidad);

    fprintf(archivoModificaciones, "%d V %d\n", codigo, cantidad);

    FILE* archivoTemporal = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
    int cod;
    char nombre[100];
    int unidades;
    float precio;
    int encontrado = 0;

    while (fscanf(archivoInventario, "%d %99s %d %f\n", &cod, nombre, &unidades, &precio) == 4) {
        if (cod == codigo) {
            unidades -= cantidad;
            encontrado = 1;
        }

        fprintf(archivoTemporal, "%d %s %d %.2f\n", cod, nombre, unidades, precio);
    }

    fclose(archivoInventario);
    fclose(archivoModificaciones);
    fclose(archivoTemporal);

    remove("inventario.txt");
    rename("temp.txt", "inventario.txt");

    if (!encontrado) {
        printf("No se encontró un producto con el código especificado.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Venta realizada correctamente.\n");
    }

    archivoInventario = fopen("inventario.txt", "r"); // Reabrir el archivo en modo de lectura
}
void devolucionProducto(FILE* archivoInventario, FILE* archivoModificaciones) {
    int codigo;
    int cantidad;

    printf("Ingrese el codigo del producto a devolver: ");
    scanf("%d", &codigo);

    printf("Ingrese la cantidad a devolver: ");
    scanf("%d", &cantidad);

    fprintf(archivoModificaciones, "%d D %d\n", codigo, cantidad);

    FILE* archivoTemporal = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
    int cod;
    char nombre[100];
    int unidades;
    float precio;
    int encontrado = 0;

    while (fscanf(archivoInventario, "%d %99s %d %f\n", &cod, nombre, &unidades, &precio) == 4) {
        if (cod == codigo) {
            unidades += cantidad;
            encontrado = 1;
        }

        fprintf(archivoTemporal, "%d %s %d %.2f\n", cod, nombre, unidades, precio);
    }

    fclose(archivoInventario);
    fclose(archivoModificaciones);
    fclose(archivoTemporal);

    remove("inventario.txt");
    rename("temp.txt", "inventario.txt");

    if (!encontrado) {
        printf("No se encontró un producto con el código especificado.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Devolución realizada correctamente.\n");
    }

    archivoInventario = fopen("inventario.txt", "r"); // Reabrir el archivo en modo de lectura
}


void consultarProducto(FILE* archivoInventario) {
    int codigo;
    printf("Ingrese el codigo del producto a consultar: ");
    scanf("%d", &codigo);

    int cod;
    char nombre[100];
    int unidades;
    float precio;
    int encontrado = 0;

    while (fscanf(archivoInventario, "%d %99s %d %f\n", &cod, nombre, &unidades, &precio) == 4) {
        if (cod == codigo) {
            printf("Codigo: %d\n", cod);
            printf("Nombre: %s\n", nombre);
            printf("Unidades: %d\n", unidades);
            printf("Precio por unidad: %.2f\n", precio);

            encontrado = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!encontrado) {
        printf("No se encontró un producto con el código especificado.\n");
    }

    rewind(archivoInventario); // Restablecer el puntero del archivo al inicio
}

int main() {
    FILE* archivoInventario = fopen("inventario.txt", "r+");
    FILE* archivoModificaciones = fopen("modificaciones.txt", "a");
    int opcion;

    if (archivoInventario == NULL || archivoModificaciones == NULL) {
        printf("Error al abrir los archivos.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    do {
        printf("MENU\n");
        printf("1. Agregar producto\n");
        printf("2. Vender producto\n");
        printf("3. Devolucion de producto\n");
        printf("4. Consultar datos del producto por ID\n");
        printf("5. Salir\n");
        printf("Ingrese una opcion: ");
        scanf("%d", &opcion);

        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                agregarProducto(archivoInventario);
                break;
            case 2:
                venderProducto(archivoInventario, archivoModificaciones);
                break;
            case 3:
                devolucionProducto(archivoInventario, archivoModificaciones);
                break;
            case 4:
                consultarProducto(archivoInventario);
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("Saliendo del programa...\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Opcion invalida. Por favor, intente de nuevo.\n");
                break;
        }

        printf("\n");
    } while (opcion != 5);

    fclose(archivoInventario);
    fclose(archivoModificaciones);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que está sucediendo es que se está pasando una copia del puntero archivoInventario como parámetro, y esa copia solo se utiliza dentro de la función.

Cuando se utiliza rewind(archivoInventario) con el puntero de archivo, se está reposicionando ese puntero al inicio del archivo. Sin embargo, como el parámetro archivoInventario se pasa por valor, ese cambio solo ocurre dentro de la función.

Lo que debes hacer es pasar el puntero por referencia.

puntero a puntero.

```
void agregarProducto(FILE** archivoInventario) {
    int codigo;
    char nombre[100];
    int unidades;
    float precio;

    rewind(*archivoInventario); // cambiado

    printf("Ingrese el codigo del producto: ");
    scanf("%d", &codigo);

    if (codigo < 0) {
        printf("Solo se admiten numeros positivos. Vuelva a intentar.\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Ingrese el nombre del producto: ");
    getchar();
    fgets(nombre, sizeof(nombre), stdin);
    nombre[strcspn(nombre, "\n")] = '\0';

    printf("Ingrese el numero de unidades: ");
    scanf("%d", &unidades);

    if (unidades < 0) {
        printf("Solo se admiten numeros positivos. Vuelva a intentar.\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Ingrese el precio por unidad: ");
    scanf("%f", &precio);

    if (precio < 0) {
        printf("Solo se admiten numeros positivos. Vuelva a intentar.\n");
        return;
    }

    fprintf(*archivoInventario, "%d %s %d %.2f\n", codigo, nombre, unidades, precio);
    printf("Producto agregado correctamente.\n");
    rewind(*archivoInventario); //cambiado
}
```

Seguí el código completo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void agregarProducto(FILE** archivoInventario) {
    int codigo;
    char nombre[100];
    int unidades;
    float precio;

    rewind(*archivoInventario); // cambiado

    printf("Ingrese el codigo del producto: ");
    scanf("%d", &codigo);

    if (codigo < 0) {
        printf("Solo se admiten numeros positivos. Vuelva a intentar.\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Ingrese el nombre del producto: ");
    getchar();
    fgets(nombre, sizeof(nombre), stdin);
    nombre[strcspn(nombre, "\n")] = '\0';

    printf("Ingrese el numero de unidades: ");
    scanf("%d", &unidades);

    if (unidades < 0) {
        printf("Solo se admiten numeros positivos. Vuelva a intentar.\n");
        return;
    }

    printf("Ingrese el precio por unidad: ");
    scanf("%f", &precio);

    if (precio < 0) {
        printf("Solo se admiten numeros positivos. Vuelva a intentar.\n");
        return;
    }

    fprintf(*archivoInventario, "%d %s %d %.2f\n", codigo, nombre, unidades, precio);
    printf("Producto agregado correctamente.\n");
    rewind(*archivoInventario); //cambiado
}

void venderProducto(FILE** archivoInventario, FILE* archivoModificaciones) {
    int codigo;
    int cantidad;

    printf("Ingrese el codigo del producto a vender: ");
    scanf("%d", &codigo);

    printf("Ingrese la cantidad a vender: ");
    scanf("%d", &cantidad);

    fprintf(archivoModificaciones, "%d V %d\n", codigo, cantidad);

    FILE* archivoTemporal = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
    int cod;
    char nombre[100];
    int unidades;
    float precio;
    int encontrado = 0;

    while (fscanf(*archivoInventario, "%d %99s %d %f\n", &cod, nombre, &unidades, &precio) == 4) {
        if (cod == codigo) {
            unidades -= cantidad;
            encontrado = 1;
        }

        fprintf(archivoTemporal, "%d %s %d %.2f\n", cod, nombre, unidades, precio);
    }

    fclose(*archivoInventario);
    fclose(archivoModificaciones);
    fclose(archivoTemporal);

    remove("inventario.txt");
    rename("temp.txt", "inventario.txt");

    if (!encontrado) {
        printf("No se encontro un producto con el codigo especificado.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Venta realizada correctamente.\n");
    }

    *archivoInventario = fopen("inventario.txt", "r+");
}

void devolucionProducto(FILE** archivoInventario, FILE* archivoModificaciones) {
    int codigo;
    int cantidad;

    printf("Ingrese el codigo del producto a devolver: ");
    scanf("%d", &codigo);

    printf("Ingrese la cantidad a devolver: ");
    scanf("%d", &cantidad);

    fprintf(archivoModificaciones, "%d D %d\n", codigo, cantidad);

    FILE* archivoTemporal = fopen("temp.txt", "w");
    int cod;
    char nombre[100];
    int unidades;
    float precio;
    int encontrado = 0;

    while (fscanf(*archivoInventario, "%d %99s %d %f\n", &cod, nombre, &unidades, &precio) == 4) {
        if (cod == codigo) {
            unidades += cantidad;
            encontrado = 1;
        }

        fprintf(archivoTemporal, "%d %s %d %.2f\n", cod, nombre, unidades, precio);
    }

    fclose(*archivoInventario);
    fclose(archivoModificaciones);
    fclose(archivoTemporal);

    remove("inventario.txt");
    rename("temp.txt", "inventario.txt");

    if (!encontrado) {
        printf("No se encontro un producto con el codigo especificado.\n");
    } else {
        printf("Devolucion realizada correctamente.\n");
    }

    *archivoInventario = fopen("inventario.txt", "r+");
}

void consultarProducto(FILE* archivoInventario) {
    int codigo;
    printf("Ingrese el codigo del producto a consultar: ");
    scanf("%d", &codigo);

    int cod;
    char nombre[100];
    int unidades;
    float precio;
    int encontrado = 0;

    while (fscanf(archivoInventario, "%d %99s %d %f\n", &cod, nombre, &unidades, &precio) == 4) {
        if (cod == codigo) {
            printf("Codigo: %d\n", cod);
            printf("Nombre: %s\n", nombre);
            printf("Unidades: %d\n", unidades);
            printf("Precio por unidad: %.2f\n", precio);

            encontrado = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!encontrado) {
        printf("No se encontro un producto con el codigo especificado.\n");
    }

    rewind(archivoInventario);  
}

int main() {
    FILE* archivoInventario = fopen("inventario.txt", "r+");
    FILE* archivoModificaciones;

    int opcion;

    if (archivoInventario == NULL) {
        printf("Error al abrir el archivo de inventario.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    do {
        printf("MENU\n");
        printf("1. Agregar producto\n");
        printf("2. Vender producto\n");
        printf("3. Devolucion de producto\n");
        printf("4. Consultar datos del producto por ID\n");
        printf("5. Salir\n");
        printf("Ingrese una opcion: ");
        scanf("%d", &opcion);

        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:
                agregarProducto(&archivoInventario); // cambiado
                break;
            case 2:
                archivoModificaciones = fopen("modificaciones.txt", "a");
                venderProducto(&archivoInventario, archivoModificaciones); // cambiado
                fclose(archivoModificaciones);
                break;
            case 3:
                archivoModificaciones = fopen("modificaciones.txt", "a");
                devolucionProducto(&archivoInventario, archivoModificaciones); // cambiado
                fclose(archivoModificaciones);
                break;
            case 4:
                consultarProducto(archivoInventario); 
                break;
            case 5:
                printf("Saliendo del programa...\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("Opcion invalida. Por favor, intente de nuevo.\n");
                break;
        }

        printf("\n");
    } while (opcion != 5);

    fclose(archivoInventario);

    return 0;
}
```

**fuente**  :

[**geeksforgeeks.org**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cpp-pointers/)
[**learn-c.org**](https://www.learn-c.org/en/Pointers)